# List Box Item gets deselected when its TextBox looses focus

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, keyboard-events

In my application I have a `ListBox` whose `ListBoxItems` are rendered as `TextBoxes`. I want the item to get selected whenever the `TextBox` gains keyboard focus. I have applied a following `Trigger` to it:

```
<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
</Trigger>
```

However, what I don't want is the item to get deselected when the `TextBox` looses focus, and this is what I currently get. This means that I'm unable to, for instance, change the font size within the `TextBox` by choosing it from a `ComboBox`.

The above code is defined in a `Template` in a `ResourceDictionary` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Storyboard` to select your item when it gets focus so it works only for selecting

```xml
    <ListBox ...>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- your DataTemplate -->
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotKeyboardFocus">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsSelected">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

this way item won't be automatically unselected when it looses focus

Comment: Splendid! This is exactly what I needed, but for one problem. Oddly enough, whenever I now set the selection somewhere in the code, like this: `SelectedTextBox = MyTexTBoxes[0];' where SelectedTextBox is the property to which ListBox's 'SelectedItem' property is bound, it won't get selected. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Yes, but the problem I described in my previous comment appeared. I have a method in my ViewModel, where I add new elements to the ListBox. And the newly added item is supposed to get selected. Now it won't, unless I actually click away from the ListBox. But I suppose I need to compromise here, unless you have an idea.

Comment: Do you use this `IsSelected` binding for anything else then selecting newly added items? If no then you could bind\change instead `ListBox.SelectedItem`